# How to choose inputs to maximize reward for an ordered dataset?

Tags: predictive-modeling, model-selection

Consider the following problem, simplified:

Let's say that you have some data where you have only 5 columns/attributes.
One of them can be seen as a **reward**. How well we performed at a given run.
The other two attributes, let's say x and y are our input to the system. A human hand picked those **x**, **y** values and they were recorded.
Another two attributes are observations from sensors. These are not inputs and we have no control over them. Let's call them **ob1** and **ob2**.
All are real values (nothing is discrete).

One idea is to look at this dataset as an ordered dataset.
We are asked to **choose input values x and y** that **maximize our reward**.

We have available ~70.000 instances of this five-tupled dataset

*This is one approach that comes into mind but not sure if it is correct in principle or the simpler one.

We could build a predictor which takes as input the four attributes (x, y, ob1, ob2) and has as target the reward.

Then try a repetitive process for the inputs by using reinfocement learning (?) to get the inputs that maximize the reward?..*

Comment: Look up "reinforcement learning" and "active learning".

Comment: Are x and y continuous? If not, how many choices do x and y have?

Comment: yes continuous, not discrete

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a **reinforcement learning** question with **continuous action space**. `(ob1, ob2)` is the observation, `(x, y)` the action, and `reward` the reward.

You may refer to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02971) from [DeepMind](https://deepmind.com), which provides a general deep Q-learning way solving this type of question, including some physics tasks.

However, as I don't have your data, I'm not sure if you have sufficient instances. ~70,000 instances with 4 features is (roughly) sufficient for general ML problems, but in reinforcement learning world, people use a simulation environment which is able to generate infinite samples, thus ~70,000 instances may be the bottleneck.

If you encounter such problem, you may try classic reinforcement learning (without "deep") techniques.